# Fetch select options from database and pass the selected option to PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, variables

Code excerpt for populating the options in HTML select from the database query:

```
<?php
// Connect to the database
$mydb = new wpdb('***','***','***','***');

// run the query to fetch the options
$rows = $mydb->get_results("select distinct(Region) from tblusers order by 
Region asc;");
?>

<!-- Form -->
<form method='post' action='success.php'>
<b><h1>Stuur SMS aan Streek</h1></b>

<b>Kies Streek:</b>
<select id='txtReg' name='txtReg'></option>
<?php 
// populate the options
foreach ($rows as $row) { 
echo "<option value=$row->Id>$row->Region ? 'selected="selected"' : '' 
</option>";
} 
?>

</select>
<br/>

<b>Boodskap:</b>
<textarea id='txtMsg' name='txtMsg' rows=5 cols=65 style='width:50%;'> 
</textarea>
<br/>

<input type='reset' value='Kanselleer'> | <input class="button" 
type='submit' value='Stuur SMS aan Streek'>
</form>
```

The success.php page that has to display the option that was selected:

```
<?php
$txtReg = $_POST['txtReg'];

echo $txtReg;
```

All working, except when I select a option from the dropdown, how do I pass it to the success page as it is not displaying when I try to echo the variable.

Comment: Please note: The options in the select are populated from a database query. A option is then selected from the dropdown, and that option value then needs to be passed on to the success page.

Comment: Yup, look at my answer and make the changes and it should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some syntax problems associated with your select tag and how you are generated your option tags.

**Updated**

```
<?php
// Connect to the database
$mydb = new wpdb('***','***','***','***');

$query = "SELECT distinct(Region) 
FROM tblusers
Order By 
Region ASC";    

$rows = $mydb->get_results($query);

var_dump($rows);

?>

<!-- Form -->
<form method='post' action='success.php'>

  <b><h1>Stuur SMS aan Streek</h1></b>

  <b>Kies Streek:</b>
  <select id='txtReg' name='txtReg'>
    <?php 
    // populate the options
    foreach ($rows as $row) { 
    echo '<option value="' . $row->Region . '">' . $row->Region . '</option>';
    } 
    ?>
  </select><br/>

  <b>Boodskap:</b>
  <textarea id='txtMsg' name='txtMsg' rows=5 cols=65 style='width:50%;'></textarea><br/>

  <input type='reset' value='Kanselleer'> | <input class="button" type='submit' value='Stuur SMS aan Streek'>

</form>
```

Another problem you might be having is your query.  Looks like you may not have the ID field being returned in your data.  If that field is not in your query then the value in your options tag will be empty.

A solution might be to change the `$row->Id` to `$row->Region` in the value of the option tag.

That should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: it still does not work - it's supposed to be as simple as getting the value from the post variable but it does not work. Is it not maybe because the select is echoed while the rest are actual HTML code? Could this not have effect?

I have tried:

    $txtReg = $_REQUEST['txtReg'];
    echo $txtReg;

And I have tried:

    $txtReg = $_POST['txtReg'];
    echo $txtReg;

Comment: please run `var_dump($rows)` before your loop and post in your answer.  Thanks

Comment: there are many many duplicate regions in the database as many users are from the same place, thus the Id is unique in this scenario.

array(5462) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3138 (2) { ["Region"]=> string(0) "" ["Id"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#3......

Comment: Please copy and paste the current code in your script and run please.

Comment: if I run the above without the Id:

array(290) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3138 (1) { ["Region"]=> string(0) "" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#3139 (1) { ["Region"]=> string(13) " Randfontein" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#3140 (1) { ["Region"]=> string(10) " Alberton " } [3]=> object(stdClass)#3141 (1) { ["Region"]=> string(10) " Bellville".....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181743/discussion-between-joseph-j-and-andre-van-rensburg).

Comment: It is never necessary to duplicate the option tag's text as its value attribute.  Just omit the value attribute declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You can add hidden field for store selected option. Update that hidden field value when changing option by using jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this,

`echo "<option value=$row->Id>$row->Region ? 'selected="selected"' : ''`

to

```
$value = 'whatever your value';

echo "<option value='". $value ."' />
```

What I can see is quotes are missing from your value.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your code. When you want an option to be selected you just write an attribute "selected" like this: `<option value="myValue" selected></option>`
in this case what you are doing is, you are assigning "selected" to option's value;

Your code should look like something like this:

```
  <?php 
 // populate the options
   foreach ($rows as $row) { 
   echo "<option value='".$row->Id."' ";

   if($row->id == $row->Region) echo "selected";
   echo "> SomeOption"; // Close the option tag and add any text inside


   echo "</option>";
   } 
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 errors in your code, you not passing the value in option and the logic for selection is `==` not `>`

```
<?php
// Connect to the database
$mydb = new wpdb('***','***','***','***');
// run the query to fetch the options
$rows = $mydb->get_results("select distinct(Region) from tblusers order by Region `asc;"); `
?>
<!-- Form -->
<form method='post' action='success.php'>
<b><h1>Stuur SMS aan Streek</h1></b>
<b>Kies Streek:</b>
<select id='txtReg' name='txtReg'></option>
<?php 
// populate the options
foreach ($rows as $row) { 
echo "<option value='".$row->Id."' ".($row->Id==$row->Region) ? 'selected' : ''."></option>"; 
}
?>
</select>
<br/>
<b>Boodskap:</b>
<textarea id='txtMsg' name='txtMsg' rows=5 cols=65 style='width:50%;'> 
</textarea>
<br/>
<input type='reset' value='Kanselleer'> | <input class="button" type='submit' value='Stuur SMS aan Streek'> 
</form>
```